# Why is this value mapping not colouring text in grafana 8.2?

Tags: grafana

Using grafana 8.2, I want to set text color in a table based on a specific text value. I checked on [this official documentation](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels-visualizations/configure-value-mappings/) to achieve it. However, there is no color applied to the text, as you can see in the following screenshot:

[image]

As there is a [table example](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels-visualizations/configure-value-mappings/#table-example) in the documentation, I assume it is supposed to work. (Plus, it's here, so...)

What I am doing wrong and how may I color cell text based on their value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, nevermind, forgot to set "Cell display mode" to "Color text", as the documentation said...

[image]